# Unable to deploy the Node.js AWS Lambda function to Docker

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am developing a REST API with Node.Js. my technology stack is AWS Lambda, API Gateway and RDS (MySQL). Below is my code

**roles.js**

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const con = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : "*****.rds.amazonaws.com",
  user     : "*****",
  password : "*****",
  port     : 3306,
  database : "******"
});

exports.lambdaHandler = (event, context, callback) => {
  // allows for using callbacks as finish/error-handlers
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
  const sql = "select * from role";
  con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;

    var response = {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "body": JSON.stringify(result),
        "isBase64Encoded": false
    };
    callback(null, response)
  });
};

exports.selectRoleByIDHandler = (event, context, callback) => {

    const { id } = event.queryStringParameters;
    console.log("id", id); 

    // allows for using callbacks as finish/error-handlers
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
    const sql = "select * from role where idRole = "+id;
    con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
  
      var response = {
          "statusCode": 200,
          "headers": {
              "Content-Type": "application/json"
          },
          "body": JSON.stringify(result),
          "isBase64Encoded": false
      };
      callback(null, response)
    });
  };
```

Below is my `template.yaml`

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  node2

  Sample SAM Template for node2
  
# More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 100
    VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - sg-sdsdsdsd
        SubnetIds:
          - subnet-ssdsds

Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: hello-world/
      Handler: app.lambdaHandler
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /hello
            Method: get
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaRole.Arn
      
  RoleFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: hello-world/
      Handler: roles.lambdaHandler
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /roles
            Method: get
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaRole.Arn

  SelectRolesByIDFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: hello-world/
      Handler: roles.selectRoleByIDHandler
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /selectRoleByIDHandler
            Method: get
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaRole.Arn
 
  LambdaRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      Path: /
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: root
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces
                  - ec2:CreateNetworkInterface
                  - ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface
                  - ec2:DescribeInstances
                  - ec2:AttachNetworkInterface
                Resource: '*'
```

When I try to execute the `sam local invoke`, i get the following error

```
Error: You must provide a function logical ID when there are more than one functions in your template. Possible options in your template: ['HelloWorldFunction', 'RoleFunction', 'SelectRolesByIDFunction']
```

Now, I have 2 questions.

1. How to solve this issue?
2. Is it a bad practice to have more than one function in a single file in AWS Lambda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, I had to invoke this as `sam local invoke HelloWorldFunction` . The `HelloWorldFunction` is the function name I need to deploy.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to build Lambda functions via the AWS SDK for Javascipt.  Have you looked at the AWS examples in the ***AWS SDK for JavaScript V3 DEV Guide***. There are end to end instructions on how to build Lambda function using the JS API that can help you.

See this topic and the child topics in the TOC:

[Cross-service examples for the AWS SDK for JavaScript](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/tutorials.html)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This works fine when deployed to aws. Only issue is when it is in local environment, Docker. I actually edited the SAM Hello World template for Node.JS so I guess the setup and everything is fine. I didnt add the database creation part etc, which I do not need in this project.

Comment: I found the issue, I had to invoke this as `sam local invoke HelloWorldFunction` . The `HelloWorldFunction` is the function name I need to deploy. Do you know how I can invoke the whole set of functions, instead of one by one?